# why is this giving me an infinite loop

Tags: ruby, infinite-loop

I dont know why it is an infinite loop. I know current is size=1 and I know the infinite loop is in the .each.

```
while current!= nil do 
  distance+=1 
  discovered[current] = true
  print move[current].size

  move[current].each{ |coord|
    if discovered[coord] == nil then 
      if paths[distance] == nil then
        paths[distance] = Array.new 
      end 
      paths[distance].push(coord)
      to_visit.push(coord)
    end 
  }

  current = to_visit.delete_at(0)
end
```

Comment: Well firstly change "while current!= nil do " to "while current do ", and change "discovered[coord] == nil" to "discovered[coord].nil?". TBH this code looks rather procedural, not object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to say without knowing the contents of `move` specifically. I assume it contains other "grid units" that you can move to based on your current location?

If that is the case, the reason could be that the `move` for the next grid unit also references the current one. It is enough that two grid units reference each other in `move` for an infinite loop.

I cleared up your code a bit. If this doesn't help, please post the contents of `move` for a more accurate answer.

```
while current do 
  distance += 1 
  discovered[current] = true

  move[current].each do |coord|
    unless discovered[coord] 
      paths[distance] ||= Array.new  
      paths[distance].push(coord)

      to_visit.push(coord)
    end 
  end

  current = to_visit.delete_at(0)
end
```

Comment: I'm looking at `move['(0,3)']` which contains an array `[(0,2)]` and the each loop just repeats `(0,2)` over and over.  It's not self-referencing.

Comment: What's in `move['(0,2)']`?

Comment: {"0,1"=>["0,0", "1,1"], "0,2"=>["1,2", "0,3"], "0,3"=>["0,2"], "1,0"=>["1,1", "2,0"], "1,1"=>["1,2", "1,0", "0,1", "2,1"], "1,2"=>["1,1", "2,2", "0,2"], "2,0"=>["2,1", "1,0"], "2,1"=>["3,1", "1,1", "2,0", "2,2"], "2,2"=>["2,1", "1,2", "2,3"], "2,3"=>["3,3", "2,2"], "3,1"=>["2,1", "3,2"], "3,2"=>["3,1"], "3,3"=>["2,3"]}
this is the coordinates and values of each has

Comment: The problem is `0,2` has a reference to `0,3`, and `0,3` has a reference back to `0,2`. When you traverse over `0,2`, `0,3` is added to `to_visit`, when you visit `0,3`, `0,2` is added, and so on, ad infinitum.

Comment: Why is 0,3 being added to to_visit when i am checking discovered

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I misread the nesting. Let me run some tests with this data.

Comment: Hm. With the values for `move` that you provided, the scripts finishes without problem for me, using both your code and mine, and for different values of `current`. I implied these: `distance = 0`, `discovered = {}`, `paths = {}`, `to_visit = []`.